# How does webmapping with QGIS Server work?

Tags: qgis, web-mapping, qgis-server

I understand the main step is to install it on a server, obviously. But what are the other things that have to be done in order to publish an interactive QGIS map on the internet?

(For example, I'm wondering at what point are the widgets (for navigation, search bar, ...) defined to appear on the webpage, etc.)

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Answer (score 0):

Simple explaination - You have to create a project in QGIS desktop, make all the settings relevant to the QGIS Server, then upload that project file and the data to the server. see https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_ogc/server/getting_started.html#configure-your-project